# Colored git output in eshell

Tags: eshell, colors

I'm using emacs inside a mintty (configured to say it's xterm-256color) terminal on cygwin. `list-colors-display` works fine. and colors are displayed in dired listings etc. Now I set the color for `git branch` current branch to be `yellow reverse`. However, neither shell nor eshell windows display the correct color; instead, the current branch is shown in default color. In an `ansi-term` window, or Outside of emacs, inside the same terminal, it displays as it should.

I have this in my `.emacs`:

```
(add-hook 'eshell-preoutput-filter-functions  'ansi-color-apply)
```

Any way to get these colors to display inside the shell or eshell windows?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in eshell with a graphical Emacs, having set `git config --global color.ui always` running `git diff`.  Could you provide more detailed steps?

Comment: does my answer below help you or is anything about it unclear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eshell and `shell-mode` both use `ansi-color.el` to turn ansi color codes into faces.  `ansi-color.el` supports the following faces:

```
Parameter  Description        Face used by default
  0        default            default
  1        bold               bold
  2        faint              default
  3        italic             italic
  4        underlined         underline
  5        slowly blinking    success
  6        rapidly blinking   warning
  7        negative image     error
```

"negative image" is "reverse" and it is mapped to the `error` face.  When I configure my repository such...

```
[color]
        ui = always
[color "branch"]
        current = yellow reverse
```

...and run `git branch` I see my local branches, and the current branch is rendered in bold yellow.  When I put point onto the yellow text and run `describe-face` I see that it is in fact rendered with the `error` face.

You can customise `ansi-color-faces-vector` to assign a different face other than `error` to "negative image"/"reverse".

You do not need `(add-hook 'eshell-preoutput-filter-functions  'ansi-color-apply)` to use ansi colors in eshell.